# ignoring last uri segment via mod_rewrite or CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, uri

I was just wondering if it is possible to ignore the last URI segment of my application via either mod_rewrite or CodeIgniter. I don't want a redirect away or a remove the URI segment. I just want my app to not know it exists. So in the browser the client will see:

http://example.com/keep/keep/ignore/

but the app is only aware of:

http://example.com/keep/keep/

The idea is, if JavaScript detects /ignore/ in the URI, it will trigger an action.

/ignore/ may appear as 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th segment, but will only ever appear as the final one and may sometimes not appear at all.

I found some info online about ignoring sub-directories with mod-rewrite, but none of them really work like this.

**

Incase any CodeIgniters suggest passing it as an unused extra parameter to my method - The app has far too many controllers and far too many wildcard routes for this to work site wide.

I think a mod_rewrite solution would be best if possible. If not, perhaps it can be done with a CodeIgniter pre-controller hook or something, but I'm not sure how that would work.

**EDIT: How I got it to work**

For anyone else who would ever like to know the same thing - in the end I overwrote _explode_segments() in MY_URI to not include this segment.

Comment: Unless you're calling the `index()` function of a controller, the extra url segment will be ignored anyways. Why don't you just use a query string or hash? This sounds like not that good of an idea.

Comment: Could use hash, but want to try something different and use a different character instead. Bit of an experiment really.

Answer (score 0):

With the URI class you can check and detect what URI's are and what they have.

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

Check out the user guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html